# How to import stuff from a Python package to a submodule

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I have the following structure:

```
seqio/
  __init__.py
    fasta.py
```

Code in Fasta.py need a class named `seq` from `__init__.py`. So I tried to import like the followings:

```
from seqio import seq
from . import seq
```

Neither of them works. How do I import it?

Comment: How are you executing your code? That also is part of the game

Comment: is 'seqio/'s parent directory in `sys.path`?

Comment: @Willemoes There is an executing main script at the same directory as seqio.

Comment: @khaldi Nope, it is not.

Comment: However, say there is a sibling file at the same dir as `fasta.py`. Such as `foo.py`, in fasta.py I can do `from .foo import xxx` just fine.

Comment: first of all, you are not following python standards, \__init\__ is not used for defining classes. the purpose of files is to define import statements for child modules.
Read this article for more details:- 
https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/

Comment: @Mr.J If that's the case then I have no other questions about importing, then.